# How to generate a Joomla password?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I need to use Joomla crypt password, to be able to register an user.
What i'm using right now is:

```
$query="update table_user set password=md5(password) where id_user='{$form->data['id_user']}'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

My question is: how to transform this password into a valid and crypted like joomla passwords?

This question is not duplicated cause old questions is very olds and cant be applicated currently.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? Also, can I suggest you please ask your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) which is the dedicated Stack Exchange network for Joomla related questions

Comment: The latest version 3.4.8

Comment: check this https://docs.joomla.org/Resetting_a_user_password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla 3.x uses Bycrypt, not MD5 so your current method is incorrect.

You can use the following to generate the hash:

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
JUserHelper::hashPassword($password);
```

Where `$password` is the password variable.

You may also want to consider using Joomla coding standards for your database query:

https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Hope this helps

#### Update:

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');

$password = 'however you get the password';
$hash = JUserHelper::hashPassword($password);

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->update($db->quoteName('table_user'))
      ->set($db->quoteName('password') . ' = ' . $db->quote($hash))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id_user') . ' = ' . (int)$form->data['id_user']);
 
$db->setQuery($query);
 
$result = $db->execute();
```

You will also need to update `$password = 'however you get the password';` as I don't know where you're getting the password from

Comment: @lodder : I think joomla still using `MD5`.  https://docs.joomla.org/Resetting_a_user_password

Comment: @TiagoP.C - Updated my answer

Comment: I'm not using standart dabatase query because i'm not using joomla's users table, i've created my table to register users. Can u update your answers with this case?

Comment: @TiagoP.C - You can still use Joomla coding methods for your database query, if if they are custom tables ;) Anyway, I've updated the answer again, using the data from your question

Comment: I'll problably accept this answer as correct, but i wil test it later. Anyway thanks alooot for the help and your time @Lodder! :))

Comment: @Lodder Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in :(

Comment: @TiagoP.C - It should specific a line the error is coming from...could you tell me which code snippet is on that line?

Comment: $password= '{$form->data['id_user']}'; this line! @Lodder

Comment: @TiagoP.C - That line is different to what I have provided you with. Please try using my code, else update your question with your full new code so it can be debugged ;)

Comment: in that line i changed your text 'however you get the password' to '{$form->data['password']}'. is it wrong?

Comment: @TiagoP.C -  Try using `$password = $form->data['password'];`

Comment: it worked very nice! @Lodder sorry for inconvenience and thanks alot again for time and pacience :D

Comment: @TiagoP.C - You're welcome. Glad it's all working now :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do in following manner.

```
query= "UPDATE table_user SET password=MD5(‘new password’) WHERE usertype = 'Super Administrator'";

$db->setQuery($query);

$db->query();
```

Comment: Joomla 3.4 does not use MD5